# Remove horizontal scroll bar in mobile

Tags: html, css

I am finding it difficult to remove the horizontal scroll bar on mobile devices and i really need some one that can help me remove it please would really appreciate it .

```
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```

CSS

```
{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}


body
{

  overflow-x:hidden;
  overflow-y:scroll;
  width:100%;
}
.header
{
    background-image:linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.7),rgba(0,0,0,0.7)),url(../img/website-startups.jpg);
    height:100vh;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Not seeing any issues with what you posted.  Is it hosted? can I take a look?

Answer (score 1):

This will disable the scroll bar for you

```
    ::-webkit-scrollbar {
display: none;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can hide your scrollbar with the css below..
Add this to the page where you don't want people to see your scrollbar

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-track
{
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px transparent;
    background-color: transparent;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar
{
    width: 6px;
    background-color: transparent;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
{
    background-color: transparent;
}
```